# Decode Proprietary Data GPRMC Data - Yamaha GPS Data logger

Tags: gps, decode, nmea

This is a long shot, but I have been trying to convert a .ctrk file which has been downloaded from a Yamaha Motorbike Data logger to a readable format.

If I open the file with Notepad++ there is some readable text, mostly the GPRMC data which I can convert to GPS coordinates, speed, time, etc... however the file 'should' also contain 18(i think) other data points(Lean angles, engine RPMs, G forces etc...).

In Notepad++ the data between the GPRMC data just shows as Start of headers, Null, Escape characters,(ENO,DC4,EOT,STX) and such like.

RAW data in Hex

```
24 47 50 52 4D 43 2C 30 34 32 37 32 35 2E 38 30 30 2C 41 2C 33 33 34 38 2E 32 33 31 38 2C 53 2C 31 35 30 35 32 2E 32 31 31 30 2C 45 2C 30 2E 30 32 2C 32 37 36 2E 35 38 2C 32 30 30 32 31 35 2C 2C 2C 44 2A 37 35 0D 0A 01 00 19 00 C6 02 19 1B 04 05 14 02 DF 07 09 02 00 00 06 0D A9 00 06 00 80 01 00 1B 00 EA 02 19 1B 04 05 14 02 DF 07 11 05 00 00 08 96 7C 50 6A 58 2C 60 10 01 00 1B 00 EA 02 19 1B 04 05 14 02 DF 07 1B 05 00 00 08 FF FF FF FF 80 00 00 00 01 00 1A 00 FE 02 19 1B 04 05 14 02 DF 07 26 02 00 00 07 0C E8 E8 EB E8 28 40 01 00 1B 00 0C 03 19 1B 04 05 14 02 DF 07 15 02 00 00 08 00 06 00 01 F3 22 06 00 01 00 1B 00 0F 03 19 1B 04 05 14 02 DF 07 58 02 00 00 08 52 16 B1 7B 00 00 75 46 01 00 1B 00 13 03 19 1B 04 05 14 02 DF 07 60 02 00 00 08 00 02 00 93 00 00 00 8C 01 00 17 00 1D 03 19 1B 04 05 14 02 DF 07 64 02 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 00 19 00 1D 03 19 1B 04 05 14 02 DF 07 68 02 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 04 00 01 00 1B 00 23 03 19 1B 04 05 14 02 DF 07 50 02 00 00 08 1B 48 1B 0A 1F 40 20 00 02 00 56 00 26 03 19 1B 04 05 14 02 DF 07 24 47 50 52 4D 43 2C 30 34 32 37 32 35 2E 39 30 30 2C 41 2C 33 33 34 38 2E 32 33 31 38 2C 53 2C 31 35 30 35 32 2E 32 31 31 30 2C 45 2C 30 2E 30 32 2C 32 37 36 2E 35 38 2C 32 30 30 32 31 35 2C 2C 2C 44 2A 37 34
```

Any ideas how I'd go about decoding this data which I'm assuming is a proprietary format. I have no idea where to start.

Thanks
James

**Data in Hex editor**
[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJy7G.jpg

Comment: Did you look, e.g. in GPS babel? They may get your format, or just you can see how many proprietary formats are designed, usually there is not much new on new formats. And you should use better tools (not Notepad++) for such works (e.g. a binary editor) or better one program where you interactively you print chars, numbers (in different formats), you try to decode, etc. Non ASCII characters gives us nothing relevant.

Comment: Just tried GPS Babel, setting the input to a few of the .trk formats without any luck. I guess its a case of going through each of the formats to see if it can read it.

Comment: All I've managed to do so far is, with some certainty is that it looks like some of the Hex is Japanese characters encoded in UTF-16(Makes sense as Yamaha is a Japanese company). But I can't see any values that look like the data I'm expecting to see.

I tried every format in GPS Babel with no luck.

Comment: Did you contacted Yamaha? Note: with proprietary format, there is no guarantee that one could decode the data [with reasonable effort]

Comment: I did email Yamaha motorsport requesting a contact for the application, but I didn't get a response.

I don't think I'm going to get anywhere with this. Other than replacing the data logger from the OEM one.

Thanks Anyway

Comment: Over a year later and still no progress :( 

I did find some software called WinOLS which has an option to graph the data(link below), which does look a little like it is pulses / ticks of data... but I still can't workout what values they are :(
https://imgur.com/a/ZIORYGn